# Error in rounding off floating point value for collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, rounding-error

I want to get rid of one pixel issue on my device.I am designing a calendar which looks like below

[image]

I am using a UICollectionViewCell for this purpose

```
   - (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
   return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,0,0,0);  // top, left, bottom, right
}

- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CGFloat collectionViewWidth = (CGRectGetWidth(collectionView.frame) / 7);
    CGFloat collectionViewHeight = 48;
    return CGSizeMake(collectionViewWidth, collectionViewHeight);
}
```

The problem is that if I increase width even by 0.0000001 point then the number of cells draw per line is 6 instead of 7. I have tried increasing the UIEdgeInset (by 0.00001) as well but it's the same issue. The properties for flow layout are set appropriately.

```
 layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0.0f;
 layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0.0f;
```

How do I make cell size consistent without leaving the gap ? The actual width of the cell is 53.571428571428569 (375/7). If I round the value to 53.58 then I get the below view 
[image]

Answer (score 6):

This is a very popular problem, the fastest way to resolve it use collectionViewWidth % 7 == 0 for cell size

For example your collectionViewWidth == 320. Cell == 320/7 == 45.7142857, U simply should use collectionViewWidth == 322, and your problem are resolved, because cell == 46

That the increase wasn't noticeable collectionViewWidth U have two option

- First, if you collectionViewWidth == screenWidth, simply align to the center and edges will hide out of screen limits
- Second  if you collectionViewWidth < screenWidth, use UIview to container for collectionView, and use clipTobounds, edges will hide out of container limits.

Comment: you have a good point. I am aware that setting width to % 7 does resolve the problem. I am looking for understanding of more in-depth solution of how UIKit deals with points to pixels conversion and if there is a way to override those behaviors in case of floating point error occurs.

Comment: I encountered the same problem recently (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44380440/ios-uicollectionview-spacing-precision) In my case, the width of the cells is 103.5, which shouldn't have rounding issue, but I still ended up having unwanted vertical lines. Looks like the best way of dealing with this is to have a small margin between all the cells, but that's a compromise on the UI.

Answer (score 1):

To get rid of one pixel try using these delegate methods of `UICollectionView`:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return -0.5;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                   layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{
    return -0.5;
}
```

or, alternatively:

```
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = -0.5;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = -0.5;
```

It may happen that you would have to set one of these to `0.0`, while the other to `-0.5`. Try playing with it.

Comment: It didn't worked. -ve values are ignored by minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex attribute I tried a possible range of -0.1  to -100